# Uploading Image in MySQL database PHP Error

Tags: php, mysqli

The if statement is not running .It works fine with the tutorial I have followed but when i have implemented it in my code it fails.The error is Undefined index: thumbnailPic, 
The HTML code is :

```
<label >Thumbnail Picture<text>*</text></label><br>
<input type="file" name="thumbnailPic" id="pic"><br>
<label >Original Picture<text>*</text></label><br>
<input type="file" name="originalPic" id="pic"><br>
```

The PHP code is :

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumbnailPic']['tmp_name']) != false) {
   $spID="NULL";
   $Quant=$_POST['quantity'];
   $Siz=$_POST['Size'];
   $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['thumbnailPic']['tmp_name'],'rb');
   $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO stitchedproduct(sp_id,quantity,size,p_id,color_id,sp_thumbnail,sp_OriginalPic) VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?,?,?,?)");
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $spID);
   $stmt->bindParam(2, $Quant);
   $stmt->bindParam(3, $Siz);
   $stmt->bindParam(4, $ProductID);
   $stmt->bindParam(5, $colour);
   $stmt->bindParam(6, $imgfp);
   $stmt->bindParam(7, $imgfp);
   $stmt->execute();
}
else
   echo "Error uploading image";
```

Comment: $_FILES['thumbnailPic'] doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,may be this code could help you a bit

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILE['image']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `product_images` (`id`, `image`, `image_name`) VALUES ('1', '{$image}', '{$image_name}')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // Error handling
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
}
```

also ur form must look like something this

```
<form action="insert_product.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File: </label><input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: It didn't work. The error is :      file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original code - tested and working.

1) Prompts for filenames 
2) Uploads files and adds them to the database.
3) will throw and exception on a database error.

The db connection is PDO not mysqli. I based this on the 'bindParam' function.

Issues with the original code:
1) spelling with variable names.
2) missing PDO::PARAM_LOB for the files.

I have hard coded all the parameters apart from the files.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php if (empty($_FILES)): // show the form... ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Upload images</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label >Thumbnail Picture<text>*</text></label><br>
      <input type="file" name="thumbnailPic" id="thumbpic"><br>
      <label >Original Picture<text>*</text></label><br>
      <input type="file" name="originalPic"  id="origpic"><br>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php endif;?>


<?php if (empty($_FILES)) {
  exit; // leave this script...
} ?>


<?php // process the input files...

// start file processing...
/* debug */ var_dump($_FILES); // show what we got as files...

// database connection...
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testmysql';
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumbnailPic']['tmp_name'])) {
//   $spID  = "NULL"; i made it auto increment
   $Quantity = 3;     // $_POST['quantity'];
   $Size  = 23;    //$_POST['Size'];
   $ProductID   = 'My Test Product1';
   $colour      = 'yucky green';

   $imgThumb     = fopen($_FILES['thumbnailPic']['tmp_name'],'rb');
   $imgOriginal  = fopen($_FILES['originalPic']['tmp_name'],'rb');

   $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO stitchedproduct(quantity, size, p_id, color_id, sp_thumbnail, sp_OriginalPic) "
                              . " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
   // $stmt->bindParam(1, $spID); auto increment
   $stmt->bindParam(1, $Quantity, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->bindParam(2, $Size);
   $stmt->bindParam(3, $ProductID);
   $stmt->bindParam(4, $colour);
   $stmt->bindParam(5, $imgThumb, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
   $stmt->bindParam(6, $imgOriginal, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

   $connection->beginTransaction();
   $stmt->execute();
   $connection->commit();

}
else
   echo "Error uploading image";


unset($connection);
?>
```